# Destination URI missing from SAML 2 LogoutRequest

Tags: adfs2.0, saml-2.0

I'm struggling to get an app working with ADFS and I'm getting the error "MSIS1010: Signed SAML message must have Destination URI specified." in the AD FS 2.0 Debug log.

The opening part of the SAML request looks like this:

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        ID="[a-hex-string]" 
        IssueInstant="2012-12-17T15:40:45.027Z" 
        Version="2.0">
```

Am I right in thinking that there should be a Destination attribute here, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Destination is an attribute in the LogoutRequest. If the message is signed the attribute must be used.

Specification of the Destination attribute can be found at page 36 of the SAML spec
http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf

Here is a post talking more about this.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3463.ad-fs-2-0-the-admin-event-log-contains-error-event-320-msis1010-signed-saml-message-must-have-destination-uri-specified.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It's reassuring to know that I'm beginning to get this.  :-)